# How can I make Excel print a different worksheet in the middle of a for loop?

Tags: excel, vba

First time poster long time user.

I have an Excel file that I use for printing labels at my workplace and currently I print out a separate cover sheet for each label. My question is how can I make Excel print the cover sheet in between each label. I have tried a few methods but it always seems to break my loop.

Here is the code for the Print Labels function,

```
`Sub PrintLabelsROI()

 Dim x As Integer
 Dim index As Integer
 Dim sheet As String
 Dim pages As Integer

 NumRows = Range("E5", Range("E5").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
 Range("E5").Select
 For x = 1 To NumRows
     index = ActiveCell.Row
         If ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
             If (Cells(index, 5).Value = "I088") Then
                 sheet = "ROI PRINT"
                 pages = Cells(index, 9).Value
             ElseIf (Left(Cells(index, 9).Value, 1) = "?") Then
                 sheet = "DF"
                 pages = Mid(Cells(index, 9).Value, 2)
             Else
                 sheet = "norm"
                 pages = Cells(index, 9).Value
             End If
        If (pages > 0) Then
            ' VB_PRINTSHEET
            Sheets(sheet).Cells(15, 6).Value = Cells(index, 6).Value
            Sheets(sheet).PrintOut Copies:=pages
        End If
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next
End Sub`
```

I created a sperate SUB to print the cover sheet called VB_PRINTSHEET

```
Sub VB_PRINTSHEET()
    Worksheets("PICKSHEET").PrintOut , Copies:=1
End Sub`
```

I then call that function in the main SUB PrintLabelsROI but no matter where I put it, my loop breaks or prints the cover sheet over and over again.

I can share the Excel.xlsm if needed.

Sorry if this isn't clear enough, please ask any questions.

Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Comment: Is it that comma after `.PrintOut` in the `VB_Printsheet` Sub? try removing the comma and see if that works.

Comment: Hi Spencer, thanks for your time. Removing the comma makes no change, the loop still stops after the first entry in the list of label prints. Check this image out it might help explain a bit better. [![labels-list.png](https://i.postimg.cc/RZLNNtXW/labels-list.png)](https://postimg.cc/G49cf40R) It runs through this list and prints how many labels i need based on the remark value column.

Comment: @Spencer Barnes I need a coversheet (which is held on a separate worksheet in the same excel file) to print out in between each row. So for example the first row prints 2 labels then the coversheet followed by the next rows labels amount and so on.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code line-by-line using F8 to check all lines do what you expect them to? From the way you describe the problem, it would seem the issue isn't with the `VB_PRINTSHEET()` sub but more with the bit that's supposed to print all the other sheets in between the cover sheets.

Comment: I have been using the original excel file to print the labels since I started about a year ago. The cover sheet is a relatively new thing that I wanted to automate to save a bit of time in the mornings. It was written by someone else before I joined.

Comment: Now then here's the strange thing when using line-by-line F8 method it works as expected.